# How do I set up the active primary menu based on taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes, uri

I have set up a blog using a custom *Article* content type and a page View with a row style of fields.

I have set up taxonomy terms to label my *Article* content types as I make them. In my View I have a field for *Taxonomy: All Terms*, with *"Link this field to its term page"* checked on. This gives me a listing of the term links displayed for each *Article* posting. Each of these links go to a page displaying all of the *Article(blog)* postings labeled with each specific term. *(For example I have a term of "Art", and have labeled multiple postings with this. When I click on the term "Art" on any posting this brings be to a page that shows all of the postings labeled with "Art".)*

I have the same active Primary Menu *"Blog"* for my blog page and the Article pages, by using the URL Aliases and Menu Trails modules. The paths that give me an active menu are "sitename/blog", "sitename/blog/article-name", etc. *(I tried using the Context module to do this but it didn't work.)*

My issue is that I can't figure out what combination of settings I need to give me an active "Blog" primary menu for the Taxonomy term page views of the Article/blog postings. I've tried various settings in Menu Trails, and auto URL aliases, and even tried manually setting the URL alias (to "blog/art", for example) but I can't generate an active primary menu for these taxonomy term pages.